# How to run a function parallel over an array in java ( Multiple ^ on 2d array)?

Tags: java, arrays, xor

How to implement this function:

```
public static byte[] multiXorBytes(final byte ... array) {

   // this can not be implemented
   return (byte) (array[0] ^ ... ^ array[array.length - 1]);
}
```

Is there any solution doing it in a **single step** by using only a single allocation?

Context:

Line 12: How to implement this?

I would like to run the xor in one step over all arrays.

So

```
out[0] = a[0][0]^ a[1][0]^ a[2][0];
out[1] = a[0][1]^ a[1][1]^ a[2][1];

 1 public static byte[] multiXorBytes(final byte[] ... array) {
 2
 3   int size = array[0].length;
 4   for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
 5       if(array[i].length != size)
 6           throw new RuntimeException("xor needs equal lengths!");
 7   }
 8   
 9   byte[] out = new byte[size];
10
11   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
12      out[i] = (byte) (array[0][i] ^ ... ^ array[array.length - 1][i]);
13  }
14  return out;
15}
```

Comment: Well nice to vote it down but do not commend why. Or even provide any solution or hint.

Answer (score 1):

You pass the whole 2d array as parameter:

```
private static byte xor(final byte[][] array, final int i){
    byte b = array[0][i];
    for (int j = 1; j < array.length; j++)
         b = b ^ array[j][i];
    return b;
}
```

Same for a single array:

```
private static byte xor(final byte[] array){
    byte b = array[0];
    for (int j = 1; j < array.length; j++)
         b = b ^ array[j];
    return b;
}
```

Comment: How to slove the dynamic ^...^ ? array.length may be 2 or more. My solution has this line still inside (line 12) but it is no valid java code.

Comment: Yes, that's correct and the only solution I know. Is it possible to find any solution xoring a dynamic number of bytes?

Comment: That is an xor of a dynamic number of bytes. If you mean a solution that doesn't require a loop, then no.

Comment: I hoped for some fancy lambda stuff or dynamic function generation.

Comment: Why? For what? There is no gain in turning it into a lambda.

Comment: For simpler source code, performance improvements (not here, as array will not be iterate over j on  array[i,j]) and improve advanced knowledge on java

Comment: I don't see any simpler source code with lambda in that scenario. The for loop above is just readable enough. Same for performance, there is just no performance gain. You have to walk through the whole array anyways, you cannot parallelize it (which is what makes streams fast in the first place. Streams are not magically faster than for loops. Improving java knowledge is a point, but I would not use it anywhere in production.